# how to customize angular-file-uploader

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 4. I dont know how to customize angular-file-uploader. I have choosed below component.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-uploader/v/4.0.0

I wanted to customize html template or doing something while click on reset button.

In typescript file, I have written

```
import * as FileUploadComponent from "angular-file-uploader";
 @ViewChild('fileUpload1')

    public fileUpload1: FileUploadComponent;
```

but I am getting error

```
ERROR in /app/solvup-file-uploader/solvup-file-uploader.component.ts(15,25):
    Cannot find name 'FileUploadModule'.
ERROR in /app/solvup-file-uploader/services/file-uploader.service.ts (4,9): 
    Module '"/home/hostjinal/Projects/form-builder-front-end/node_modules/angular-file-uploader/index"' has no default export.
```

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a npm package to do it. Here is the code that I've written in one of my components instead of using npm package.

In the TS file

@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput;

Handler of upload click

```
public upload() {

    this.progress = 0;

    const fileBrowser = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
    if (fileBrowser.files && fileBrowser.files[0]) {

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', fileBrowser.files[0]);

      this._appHttpService.postUploadFile(formData).subscribe(res => {
        this._uploadModel = res;

        // console.log(res);

      });
    }
  }
```

Code in the httpservice.

```
  public postUploadFile(formData: FormData): Observable<uploadModel[]> {
        const uploadUrl =
         environment.serverBaseUrl +
        environment.uploadUrl;

        return this._http.post(uploadUrl, formData, this.uploadOptions)
            .map(res => {
                return <uploadModel[]>res;
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

And here is how i invoke it.

```
<button type='button' class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-upload col-sm-1" (click)="upload()"> Upload</button>
```

If you still looking at fixing your issue. Did you check the following instruction?

Import FileUploadModule inside your app.module.ts

```
import { FileUploadModule } from "angular-file-uploader";
@NgModule({
  imports: [
      ...,
      FileUploadModule,
      ...
  ]
})
```